# Batch file ping -t command

Tags: batch-file, ping

I'm making a batch file, to find mean of time of ping -t. How do I extract just the time from the ping output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from following code you will get some hint.

```
SET CONNECT=YES
PING google.com | FIND "time=" > NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET CONNECT=NO
ECHO You have %CONNECT% active connection to the Internet
```

Comment: "You have YES active connection" ?

Comment: @AdamLiss: You shouldn't try to interpret an answer literally when you are only supposed to get some hint. :)

Comment: Thanks but can you set the number as variable?

Comment: @AndriyM: You just failed the interview, and thousands of potential employers (and customers) are watching.  `SET CONNECT=an` turns the code into a user-ready solution with just a tiny bit of extra thought and _less_ code.  Details distinguish mediocre programmers from good ones.

Comment: Can you both please just store the time  in milliseconds as a variable!